# Each media segment file for MPEG-DASH is a full (.mp4) instead of fragment mp4 (.m4s)?

Tags: mpeg

I'm wondering if I can just make every media segment files as a full MP4 file instead of fragmented MP4 for a DASH264-compliant player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the DASH spec, I'd say the fragmented MP4 is the must for media segment files. Therefore, it is not possible to use a full (or non-fragmented) MP4 in DASH.